# Is is possible to override an RPM's service user account during installation?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

While doing an installation of an RPM using either `rpm` or `yum` is it possible to override the default user account that's typically defined in the RPM `.spec` file?

I'm specifically dealing with an RPM of Tomcat 8 and would like to override the service user account from tomcat8 to something else.

I suspect this isn't possible without a change to the RPM `.spec` file but wanted to see if anyone knew of a way to do this regardless.

The only methods I've seen are to create a script in the postinstall which would prompt the user.

#### References

- [Is it possible to get user's input during installation of rpm?](https://superuser.com/questions/408852/is-it-possible-to-get-users-input-during-installation-of-rpm)
- [Passing user defined argument to RPM is possible while installing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204964/passing-user-defined-argument-to-rpm-is-possible-while-installing)
- [RPM - Install time parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258647/rpm-install-time-parameters)

Comment: RPM's are generally just about getting the required files down to the client system, they don't usually take input. If you need input post-install of the RPM that's usually what activation programs are for (powerpath does this for their enforcement of licenses). Config files are only overwritten if they're either absent or the same as from the initial rpm install. Others are created with the `.rpmnew` extension. You might try putting down the config then doing the install or vice versa with config modification instead of creation.

Comment: Updating the spec file is probably overkill, though, unless you're already building them with Jenkins or something.

Comment: @Bratchley - We maintain the RPM so that is an option but I don't like it either.

Comment: If you're already building the RPM, what's stopping you from just modifying the config in a `Patch` with the value it needs?

Comment: @Bratchley - the issue is that I was asked if we could make it configurable for customers that consume the RPM that we provide. I realize I could just change it but it needs to be configurable, which I explained to them that it isn't that way on purpose within RPM, but I just wanted to see if the state had changed since looking into this before.

Comment: Most rpm %post scripts conditionally add an account if it doesn't exist. As long as the account already exists, the rpm won't create it. Can't you just precreate the account outside of the rpm?  Or are you trying to make it use a different account name?

Comment: @jsbillings - yeah I'm familiar w/ how most %post scripts do it. I was given the requirement that it be configurable, so yes the installer would be able to override the built-in user of the RPM with one of their choosing. This requirement I'm pretty sure is not possible without elaborate scripting in the %post but I was asking to make sure.

Comment: @slm Well you could always try to read the variables for username, groupname, gecos field or whatever from some standard location like /etc/sysconfig/custom_defaults or something like that. That way it's configurable by each customer, but you have to do some sanity checks on the variables, and provide default values if the custom defauls are not set.

Sadly it seems Fedora/CentOS still doesn't use any premade helper for user/group creation, as fedora-usermgmt shouldn't be used anymore, and the packaging guidelines also do it manually: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:UsersAndGroups.

Comment: @doktor5000 - that guide looks to be the answer(s) I was looking for. If you want to write it up as a formal answer I can then accept it and we'll now have this Q/A on the internet making this info more explicit and accessible. LMK & I can assist with the answer if you like.

Comment: @slm Added as answer, hope that suffices. If you have any specific questions about those scriptlets, or anything else related to rpm, just ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in the sense that you can provide arguments to rpm e.g. when installing your custom packages, to override the values contained in the package. But you can add logic in the shell scripts that are run during rpm installation, and can hence make your customizations this way.

Fedora by default does add/remove users via some scriptlets, see the fedora wiki about the details: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:UsersAndGroups and for some general information about %post/%pre-scripts and all the variations see the explanation in the Max RPM book at http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html (the section "Install/Erase-time Scripts") and for the ordering maybe https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets. For some more in-depth details, check http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nstwiki/index.php/RPM_Quick_Reference

So for your specific question, you could try to read the variables for username, groupname, gecos field or whatever (values that should be customisable on the target system) from some standard location like `/etc/sysconfig/custom_defaults` or something like that. That way it's configurable by each customer, but you have to do some sanity checks on the variables, and provide default values if the custom defauls are not set, but that's the same for all shell scripts in general.